# How to create Azure site specify resource group using azure-cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli

With this reference, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-local-git

I executed command as follows.

`$ azure site create --git my-app-name`

Then, an error message appeared.

`info:    Executing command site create
error:   The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\yokoyamt\.azure\azure.err
error:   site create command failed`

I've tried in another azure account, which I have "power-user", then 
A new Resource group was created and the app service was deployed in it.

But in this time, I haven't enough role to create new resource group.
So I guessed If I had specify resource group when I create app via azure-cli.

Can anyone put some light on this?

```
> az account list --output table
Name      CloudName    SubscriptionId                        State    IsDefault
--------  -----------  ------------------------------------  -------  -----------
従量課金  AzureCloud   my-subscription-id  Enabled  True
```

Comment: `azure site` is a classic mode(asm) command. Do you check your cli mode?

Comment: I've checked cli mode and it shows "asm", but thanks anyway, I will try & use new az command from now on.

Comment: `azure site create --git my-app-name` works for me. Do you check your account `azure account list`. Your subscription is right?

Comment: Your Azure account has subscription or multiple subscriptions?

Comment: yes, I have subscription. I've just fixed question above.

Comment: Do you check your account permission? You should give your account co-admin permission in classic Portal. New Portal does not work on it. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125930/error-fetching-vm-list-using-azure-cli-tools).

Comment: `web site` is a classic(asm) resource in Azure. `web app` is ARM mode resource.

Comment: I've found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs and followed instrctions, then finally I can create app via azure-cli. (still confusing about deploy...) Thanks for reply Walter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`azure site` is a classic(asm) mode resource, `azure web` is a arm mode resource. You should give your account co-admin permission in classic Portal. New Portal does not work on it. Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125930/error-fetching-vm-list-using-azure-cli-tools).

According to your description, you want to deploy a web app on Azure. You could use Azure CLI 2.0 to do this. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs).